# KDE 5 does not have window decorations

Tags: debian, window-manager, wayland, kde5, sddm

I'm running KDE Plasma 5.4.3 on Debian stretch/sid. I have kwin_wayland 5.4.3 and sddm 0.13.0.
I only installed the base system and then ran `apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop/testing sddm/testing` (and all updates & upgrades afterwards and before).

It kinda works - there is a nice login screen and it can create windows; However none of them have any window decorations (e.g. the minimize/maximize/close buttons are missing) which I miss dearly.

My .xsession_errors file is [here](http://pastebin.com/34QimS79)

There is [an older question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/kde-starting-without-anything-else-no-panels-no-window-manager-decorator?rq=1) with my problem, but it is for KDM which isn't used in the new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem on my kali linux(kali-rolling version).
I solved this problem, just installed 'kwin-x11'

```
sudo apt-get install kwin-x11 kwin-decoration-oxygen
```

I think this might solve your problem too.

Comment: Well, it doesn't exactly *solve* the issue but hey I got what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `plasma-applet-active-window-control`

Dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake extra-cmake-modules plasma-workspace-dev plasma-framework-dev build-essential qtcreator
```

then

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/plasma-active-window-control
```

Install

```
cd plasma-applet-active-window-control
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

then Reboot.

#### SETTING KWIN PROPERLY

if you want borderless windows you can set it in this way :

```
kate ~/.config/kwinrc
```

under `[Window]` you should put

```
BorderlessMaximizedWindows=true
```

To launch Window Manager settings type the following command:

```
kcmshell4 kwincompositing kwindecoration kwinoptions kwinrules kwinscreenedges kwintabbox
```